# is it possible org style doc (as comment) in c++ or any other programming language?

Tags: org-mode

can you use org style document in c++'s comment region?

I could open up an org doc and type there and copy the contents as a comment block inside `/* */`
I wonder if it can be done without leaving the source code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, maybe you should consider alternatives to Orgmode for **documenting your source code**, e.g., [Doxygen](https://www.doxygen.nl/manual/docblocks.html).

Orgmode is more suitable for **literate programming** where the documentation is the primary text.

Nevertheless, there are ways to show the text in the normal mode for the programming language and in Org-mode.

While you are editing the Org-comment you can switch on Org-mode with <kbd>M-x</kbd> `org-mode` <kbd>RET</kbd> and when you are done you can go back to the programming mode by <kbd>M-x</kbd> `normal-mode` <kbd>RET</kbd>.
This is only problematic if the programming language interferes with the Org-syntax.

You can even keep an `org-mode` buffer open for editing the comments in Org-mode by using [jac](https://github.com/TobiasZawada/jac).

The following picture shows you what you get with `jac`:

[image: LHS: Original buffer with its normal mode, RHS: jac buffer in Orgmode]

On the left-hand side you see the original buffer with its normal mode, on the right-hand side you have the jac buffer (generated by <kbd>M-x</kbd> `jac` <kbd>RET</kbd> and switched to Org-mode by <kbd>M-x</kbd> `org-mode` <kbd>RET</kbd>).

In this special case I use [texfrag](https://github.com/TobiasZawada/texfrag/) to display the formulae in Org-mode, but you can also use the Org-mode original `org-toggle-latex-fragment`.

Answer (score 0):

No, but if you just want code folding then take a look at `outline-minor-mode`.